# How to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{k=1}^{5} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$

I have broke it into

$ = \sum_{k=1}^{5} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} $

But I have no clue how to compute this, without brute forcing my way and calculation every iteration. I feel like there is some rule i'm unaware of.

Comment: It is better to perform partial fraction decomposition on the given fraction. Stuff is gonna cancel...

Comment: $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\ne \frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom shiet

Comment: You've been already answered. What's with all the edits?

Comment: Key step: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5} \frac{1}{k+1}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{6} \frac{1}{k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5} \frac{1}{k}+\ldots-\ldots$$

Comment: Brute forcing is quite viable here, $1/2+1/6+1/12+1/20+1/30=(30+10+5+3+2)/60$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust C'mon, you got to prefer $\frac11-\frac16$, no?

Comment: @did: of course, but I wouldn't blame a student spending the effort to evaluate the first few terms. $5$ is more on the side of $0$ than $\infty$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right. Especially, user John could have turned to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. By a partial fraction decomposition, one rather has
$$
\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}, \qquad k\ge1,
$$ then use a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).